# Filling in 100m2 blocks in ArcGIS

Tags: gis, arcgis

I have four years worth of data outlining where a species has been found in a particular area (I'm looking at whether the distribution has expanded, etc). I've managed to convert the data into a format where it shows if the species was present within a 100m2 quadrat. I've overlaid a 100m2 grid over the survey area, and I'm now at a stage where I have a coloured point at the bottom left hand corner of every 100m2 block where the species has been found (I'm really hoping this makes sense!).

However, I don't want the coloured data point in the south west corner of each block, I'd like those blocks to be completely filled in and that's where I've hit a dead end....is this even possible? I assume it is as I've seen papers with maps done like that, but I have no idea how to do it!

Comment: Sounds like your grid is a vector layer. Using a raster grid would be much easier: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?id=1312&pid=1307&topicname=Point_to_Raster_%28Conversion%29

Comment: Since you've got a spatiotemporal dataset (for data covering 4 years), it might be helpful to know how it is being stored. What is your temporal scale (species present each day, month, year)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have:
file1 = a set of points for species location
file2 = a polygon shapefile grid

use the identity tool where file2 features are being identified by file1.
Then classify the symbology of the resulting file.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to use vector data to accomplish this. If so, I would recommend creating your grid using the `DataManagement/Fishnet` tool.

1) Enter your origin coordinate and cell size.

2) Change geometry type to polygon (default is polyline).

3) Create the `fishnet.`

4) Use the `Select by location` tool to select your grid squares based on your data points.

5) Color them in.

You may even want to play around with a `spatial join` to give your grid the desired species attributes, which would allow you to use more advanced visualization techniques.